# Software patents implications and ramifications to the end user

Tags: software, liability, patents, consumer-protection

Software patents affect a small part of the world. As a citizen of a state, where software patents are not a thing, I am personally not concerned with that. However, as a developer I am concerned with my clients, as many of them are citizens in states, where software patents are a thing.

The question is about the liability of the end user - are end users potential targets for prosecution on basis of software patents, if they use software that "infringes" on a local software patent? I do understand that if I was a citizen of such a state, I'd have legal problems with releasing such software, but the question is strictly about the end user.

Is there any difference between proprietary and open source applications?

Lastly, and I don't know if it makes a difference, but I am not talking about stealing source code, but engineering something that has been engineered over and over again, until someone happened to patent it, not necessarily and usually not the first one to think of it.

EDIT: Care to explain those anonymous downvotes? No constructive criticism? Or is it just genuinely a bad thing to be concerned with your customers?

Answer (score 5):

At least in theory an end user could be sued for infringing on a patent, especially a method claim. Given the cost of a patent lawsuit, this strikes me as *extremely* unlikely to happen though, unless the user in question were an extremely large company, or something on that order.

Theoretically, the only difference between open-source software and proprietary software would be that availability of the source code makes it easier to prove use of a patent in open-source software. Releasing the software as open-source doesn't confer any immunity from patent law or anything like that though. Realistically, however, the chances of being sued for infringement if you're basically giving away the software in question are fairly remote. It rarely makes sense for a patent holder to spend millions of dollars on a lawsuit where they stand no chance of even recovering their cost (but no, that certainly should **not** be taken as legal advice that you're free to infringe on patents, or anything similar--in fact, none of this should be taken as legal advice at all).

If you can actually prove that a technique was published or publicly known and used (e.g., in a product that was offered for sale) well before the patent was applied for, the patent is probably invalid (and if proven so in court, the case would normally be dismissed with prejudice, which basically means the patent holder wouldn't be able to sue anybody else for infringement of that patent). I'd note, however, that in my experience this is *much* less common than most people imagine--many look at (for example) the title of a patent, and assume it lacks originality because it refers to some well-known technique, and ignore the claims where it details the precise differences between the previously known technique and what the patent really covers.

Just for example, the EFF used to have a web page talking about a (now long-since expired) patent on how to draw a cursor on screen. In an apparent attempt at scaring the unwary, they showed code they claimed infringed in the patent--despite the fact that the patent's "background of the invention" specifically cited the technique they showed as being previously known, and *not* covered by the patent.

Comment: My point is that common sense should not be subject to IP. I personally am genuinely not influenced by prior art, I encounter a problem and figure out a logical solution. It is only expected that anyone before me encountering those problems and possessing common sense would have come up with the same or similar solution.

Comment: @ddriver: I agree that you shouldn't be able to patent something that's obvious. Patent law (at least in the US) agrees. The problem is in deciding exactly what really is obvious--especially when many of the best inventions eluded many people for years or even decades, but seem almost blindingly obvious in hindsight.

Comment: @ddriver Common sense is not subject to IP. Patents are given in exchange for public disclosure. Averages "dudes" can certainly create new and useful inventions. It's extremely rude to suggest that all patent lawyers be fired or murdered. [This paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2185090) gives a good explanation of "hindsight bias" and how all things can look "obvious" after the fact.

Comment: @Dawn - the practical side of firing someone out of a cannon into the sun would suggest that is a joke. Not that I don't consider impeding innovation and productivity a crime worthy of prosecution. Legalized crime is still a crime.

Comment: @ddriver: IMO, you're badly mistaken. I've written a couple of blog entries about why. See: http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/09/why-most-programmers-are-wrong-about.html, and: http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/10/software-patents-part-ii.html.

Comment: @ddriver The goal of the patent system is to promote the progress of the useful arts and science, not to impede. Whether they achieve that goal is not on-topic for this site. Patents exchange a limited-term monopoly (so, yes, they explicitly impede some freedoms) for public disclosure of an invention. Please quit with the name calling ("professional mafias"). It is not only my opinion that there is no such thing as legal crime, it is the opinion of every court in the United States, Canada, and every other Common Law based jurisdiction that I know of.

Comment: @ddriver Ethics and law are different things. What is legal isn't necessarily ethical. On this site, we talk about the law, not ethics. Crime is defined by statute. We talk about the law as it is today. Whether a particular law is good policy is not on-topic for this site. FYI [European courts have held that the slide-to-unlock](http://ipkitten.blogspot.ca/2015/09/apples-european-slide-to-unlock-patent.html) is not patentable. If you think you have prior art that can invalidate the slide-to-unlock patent in the US, you can sue to have the patent invalidated.

Comment: @Dawn: Yo don't have to sue to have the patent invalidated by prior art. 35 USC 302: "Any person at any time may file a request for reexamination by the Office of any claim of a patent on the basis of any prior art cited under the provisions of section 301."

Comment: @ddriver Invalidation happens frequently: [Only 22% of ex parte re-examinations survive with all claims unchanged](http://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/ex_parte_historical_stats_roll_up_EOY2014.pdf). Here's one example - http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/08/17/uspto-finds-apple-iphone-design-patent-invalid-in-court-fight-against-samsung

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35566/discussion-on-answer-by-jerry-coffin-software-patents-implications-and-ramificat).